# Custom Drush command and Settings::get(), Config::get()

Tags: 8, drush

how can I access site configuration when in Drush command?

Global variable `$config === null` and when I use `Config::get('key')`, I get

> Error: Using $this when not in object context in Drupal\Core\Config\Config::get() (line 85 of /var/www/drupalvm/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Config.php)`

What is the recommended approach? I can't find it anywhere... thank you!

**Edit**

I actually intended to access Settings, not Config - that's where the confusion came from. `Settings::get()` works just fine. To get data from config, just follow the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get is not a static method, so it should not be called statically (using ::). Use Drupal's service container and get the config service using \Drupal::service('config'), then get your config from that.

Answer (score 1):

### Drupal 9

Inject the config factory and the site settings and then you can get all config and settings you need.

```yaml
# modules/custom/MY_MODULE/drush.services.yml
services:
  MY_MODULE.commands:
    class: \Drupal\MY_MODULE\Commands\MyModuleCommands
    arguments: ['@config.factory', '@settings']
    tags:
      - { name: drush.command }
```

```php
// modules/custom/MY_MODULE/src/Commands/MyModuleCommands.php
<?php

namespace Drupal\MY_MODULE\Commands;

use Drupal\Core\Site\Settings;
use Drush\Commands\DrushCommands;
use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;

/**
 * Provide Drush commands for MY MODULE.
 */
class MyModuleCommands extends DrushCommands {

  /**
   * The config factory.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface
   */
  protected $configFactory;

  /**
   * The site settings.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Site\Settings
   */
  protected $settings;

  /**
   * MyModuleCommands constructor.
   */
  public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $configFactory, Settings $settings) {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->configFactory = $configFactory;
    $this->settings = $settings;
  }

   /**
   * Get stuf
   *
   * @command my:stuff
   * @aliases muff
   * @usage my:stuff
   *   Get stuff from site.settings
   */
  public function getStuff() {

    $uuid = $this->configFactory->get('system.site')->get('uuid');
    $this->logger()->success($uuid);

    $batch_size = $this->settings->get('entity_update_batch_size');
    $this->logger()->success($batch_size);
  }

}
```

Comment: Does this use values overridden in settings.php? The built in drush cget command sadly does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try `drush cget configName`

[Drush config-get Documentation](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/config/config-get/)

sample:

```
drush config-get system.site
```